# Describing the ideal in polynomial ring with $n$ indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $m$ be a natural number. Describe the ideal $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)^m$ of the ring $R[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ of polynomials over $R$ in indeterminates $X_1,...,X_n$.

I know that, if $K[X,Y]$ is the ring the generators of ideal $(X,Y)^2$ are $\{X^2,XY,Y^2\}$.

Generators of ideal $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)^m$  are like $\{X_1^m,X_1^{m-1}X_2,...\}$. I know but it looks like very complex. I can not arrange the generators in a good way. Maybe I am totally wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Do you know the multi-index notation?

Comment: yeap. for instance it must be look like  ∏ Xi^t and i=1,2,...,n and t=1,2,...,m but sum of powers must be equal to m so i cant provide that.

Comment: Why not use this notation to describe the set of generators (those are homogenous polynomials of degree $m$) as $\{X_1^{t_1} \cdots X_n^{t_n} \ | \ t_1 + \cdots + t_n = m \}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of generators is the set of homogenous polynomials of degree $m$. It can be described as

$$\{X_1^{t_1} \cdots X_n^{t_n} \ | \ t_1 + \cdots + t_n = m, t_i \in \mathbb{N} \}$$.

Comment: and for all i ,ti elements of natural numbers.

Comment: yes, thanks! :)

Comment: u r wellcome =)

Comment: Now I feel stupid.. :-) Feel free to mark it as an answer if it fits to you!

Comment: i dont know how to mark it. if you tell me i can do it.

Comment: There must be a flag next to my answer (under the upvote arrows) saying "mark as answer", then the check mark will be green. Thank you :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11232/discussion-between-bis-hd-and-spectralmath)

Answer (score 5):

$(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)^m$ consists of those polynomials whose homogeneous components of degree $<m$ vanish. Roughly, they "start" at degree $\geq m$.

(In particular, the quotient $(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)^m / (X_1,\dotsc,X_n)^{m+1}$ is free over $R$ with basis the homogeneous polynomials of degree $m$. It follows that the associated graded ring $\bigoplus_m (X_1,\dotsc,X_n)^m / (X_1,\dotsc,X_n)^{m+1}$ recovers $R[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$.).